# Struggling with dynamic data

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I am try to create a graph but having problems converting the data to a format compatible with Chart JS. I'd like a graph like the one below.

[image: Graph]

The Data returned from SQL looks like this.

[image]

This data will dynamically change so I can't manually create the datasets. The data should be dynamically generated from the database.

Comment: Do you want data in JSON format?

Comment: _"This data will dynamically change so I can't manually create the datasets."_ - elaborate please, what will be dynamically changed, why those changes make you unable to create datasets? Column list look pretty static. Row list and specific values, I assume, are supposed to change someday. Otherwise it'd be a static picture, not a chart.

Comment: I'm looking at chart.js documentation and samples for bar chart at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-dataset-structure  . Did you check this source, I'm not sure if you can get what exactly you want

Comment: You have 4 labels in the x-axis, but you want to show 6 figures (3 bar in year 2016). This seems to be a problem

Comment: @Eralper - JSON format would be preferable.

Comment: @Ivan - I mean more types could be added or removed

Comment: @Eralper - "You have 4 labels in the x-axis, but you want to show 6 figures (3 bar in year 2016). This seems to be a problem" - All this means is in 2016 there were 3 types is issues created, the other years only had one. This is what I mean by dynamic, types can be added removed at anypoint.

Comment: Hi Tim, SQL Server 2016 has built-in support for JSON in SELECT statements with FOR JSON AUTO or FOR JSON PATH options

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic SQL script where labels and values are build dynamically using [SQL string concatenation](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-concatenation-function-to-sql-concatenate-strings.aspx) method with For XML Path

Please note that following script is missing the bar colors which should be dynamically appended to SQL as the same number of labels

So a similar concatenation method can be executed on a table where bar label colors are stored. After the list is fetched as a single character variable, it can be added to the @SQL at the appropriate places

```
--create table reportData (year int, type varchar(10), qty int)
--insert into reportData select 2013, 'Type 1',1
--insert into reportData select 2014, 'Type 1',2
--insert into reportData select 2015, 'Type 3',1
--insert into reportData select 2016, 'Type 2',1
--insert into reportData select 2016, 'Type 3',2
--insert into reportData select 2016, 'Type 4',4


declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @labels nvarchar(max)
declare @measures nvarchar(max)

SELECT
 @labels = 
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT distinct
      ',"' + convert(nvarchar(4),[year]) + '"'
    FROM reportData
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  )

SELECT
 @measures = 
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT 
      ',' + convert(nvarchar(4),qty)
    FROM (
        select 
            years.year, data.qty
        from (
            select distinct year from reportData
        ) years
        left join (
            select sum(qty) as qty, year from reportData group by year
        ) data on years.year = data.year
    ) Q
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  )

set @sql = N'
var data = {
    labels: ['+ @labels + '],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Graph",
            backgroundColor: [
                ''rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'',
                ''rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'',
                ''rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'',
                ''rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                ''rgba(255,99,132,1)'',
                ''rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'',
                ''rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'',
                ''rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: ['+ @measures +'],
        }
    ]
};'

print @sql
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I would prefer not to use dynamic SQL. I'd prefer SQL to return the raw data and either C# or JS to build the datasets on the fly?